# set image with data-default-file with twig symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

i have a problem... i want to show in my file input one image by default... generaly i can use `<input class="dropify" data-default-file="../plugins/bower_components/dropify/src/images/test-image-1.jpg" type="file">` , but, now i need to show a image of my DataBase mysql using twig...

i tried with this:

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.fotoUsuario, { 'attr': {'data-default-file': '{{ asset('images/usuarios/'~ tUsuario.fotoUsuario) }}'} }) }}
```

too with:

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.fotoUsuario, { 'attr': {'data-default-file': "'images/usuarios/'~ tUsuario.fotoUsuario"} }) }}
```

This way it does not work either, I also have to clarify that my image has extension jpg, but in my database I save it with format phpB228.tmp.

My problem is how I should show the image, please someone help me and tell me that I'm wrong ... thanks ...

---------------------- First Update
 when i use `<input class="dropify" data-default-file="../plugins/bower_components/dropify/src/images/test-image-1.jpg" type="file">`The result is an input with a preview of the image and works correctly. But when I use either method the result is the input without the image. After thinking well I think it is an image path problem and it is not loading correctly. Maybe if they help me in how to locate the correct path of the image could be the problem .... in symfony2 in my web folder I have 2 folders the first is bundles where all assets are stored symlink, and the other folder is images that I I created for the images that I loaded with my crud, could that be ??

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is the actual output you are receiving with each method?

Comment: I update the post, please review it

Comment: Not really sure - I can't tell if that was hardcoded output or the output of one of those commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I found the correct way to express it in twig:

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.fotoUsuario, { 'attr': {'data-default-file': '{{ asset('images/usuarios/'~ tUsuario.fotoUsuario) }}'} }) }}
```

thanks all... ;D